# Table name for devices in DCNM inventory

Tags: cisco, nms

I want to write an automation code for getting the inventory in the DCNM tool with a code. I am trying to do so with Java using JDBC. I am able to connect to the database but when I executing a query to fetch the data, it says 'no rows selected'. I want to know the table name in the database where I can get the whole inventory by running SQL queries.

Comment: You should check Cisco's programming guides for this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/cloud-systems-management/prime-data-center-network-manager/products-programming-reference-guides-list.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get this information from Cisco.  Cisco maintains programming guides for this tool at:  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/cloud-systems-management/prime-data-center-network-manager/products-programming-reference-guides-list.html